# Is there a weird bug in jQuery involving ajax calls of type DELETE?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

This is driving me nuts.

So,

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "resource",
 data: "param1=val1&param2=val2"
});
```

will send an HTTP POST request to the resource with the data, but

```
$.ajax({
 type: "DELETE",
 url: "resource",
 data: "param1=val1&param2=val2"
});
```

sends an HTTP DELETE request to the resource **without** the data.

What gives? I only have WebKit browsers to test on (Chrome/Safari), but is this some sort of jQuery bug/known issue I can't track down? Or am I using `$.ajax()` incorrectly?

Comment: Changing the request type from POST to DELETE results in either the data payload being sent or not. This seems preposterous. What am I missing?

Comment: @dakait No, not using IIS. Using Tomcat in this case.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Way back in [jQuery 1.4.3](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.3/src/ajax.js#L7), DELETE requests did not allow request bodies. That behavior seems to have changed for 1.4.4 and on, so I'm not sure what you may be encountering aside from a browser oddity.

Comment: @DominicBarnes jQuery 1.8.3.

Comment: Odd, when I issue a DELETE request with jQuery 1.8.3 on JSFiddle, the Chrome Dev Tools seems to show the data being sent correctly.

Comment: Hmm. When I dig into it with Chrome Dev Tools, I get the form data being sent correctly too. Maybe the issue is elsewhere...

Comment: This might be a Tomcat issue: http://www.spenceruresk.com/2011/11/http-delete-requests-that-include-a-body/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm officially calling this a Tomcat problem.

[Is an entity body allowed for an HTTP DELETE request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request)

Thanks @DominicBarnes and @dakait for pointing me in the right direction.

And FFS why isn't the HTTP spec explicit on this? Maddening.